# How to parse string into date?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

How can I convert a String to a Date in T-SQL?

My test case is the string: `'24.04.2012'`

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
CONVERT(datetime, '24.04.2012', 104)
```

Should do the trick. See here for more info: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Answer (score 28):

[Microsoft SQL Date Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
CONVERT(DateTime, DateField, 104)
```

Answer (score 27):

Assuming that the database is MS SQL Server 2012 or greater, here's a solution that works.  The basic statement contains the in-line try-parse:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('02/04/2016 10:52:00' AS datetime USING 'en-US') AS Result;
```

Here's what we implemented in the production version:

```
UPDATE dbo.StagingInputReview
 SET ReviewedOn = 
     ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(RTrim(LTrim(ReviewedOnText)) AS datetime USING 'en-US'), getdate()),
 ModifiedOn = (getdate()), ModifiedBy = (suser_sname())
 -- Check for empty/null/'NULL' text
 WHERE not ReviewedOnText is null 
   AND RTrim(LTrim(ReviewedOnText))<>''
   AND Replace(RTrim(LTrim(ReviewedOnText)),'''','') <> 'NULL';
```

The ModifiedOn and ModifiedBy columns are just for internal database tracking purposes.

See also these Microsoft MSDN references:

- [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- [PARSE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx)

Comment: This assumes that the OP is using Sql Server 2012+

Answer (score 9):

Although the CONVERT thing works, you actually shouldn't use it. You should ask yourself why you are parsing string values in SQL-Server. If this is a one-time job where you are manually fixing some data you won't get that data another time, this is ok, but if any application is using this, you should change something. Best way would be to use the "date" data type. If this is user input, this is even worse. Then you should first do some checking in the client. If you really want to pass string values where SQL-Server expects a date, you can always use ISO format ('YYYYMMDD') and it should convert automatically.

Comment: What about a situation where you're importing data files from some external system, and the input column happens to be in one of these formats, e.g. "05/31/2013", but which comes in as a string ?  And you're writing, say, a stored procedure to import that data, or using SSIS to import it?  Then CONVERT would be the appropriate thing to use, would it not?

Comment: Not necessarily, in the situations where MS SQL Server host analytic data models, as opposed to transaction ones, it is perfectly okay to use CONVERT because it has to deal with a lot of external sources that would not be readily coming in as a date type (as David Barrows alluded to above).

Comment: Default string literal format for dates is [YYYY-MM-DD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql)

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '24.04.2012', 103) AS Date
```

Reference:
[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: It's interesting that works.  Format 103 is dd/mm/yyyy and 104 is dd.mm.yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONVERT(DateTime, ExpireDate, 121) AS ExpireDate
```

will do what is needed, result:

```
2012-04-24 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work for what the OP posted even for different language settings.  Try it.  If it actually does work for you, then please post what your current language setting is.  Thanks.  Here's the code to try... SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, '24.04.2012', 121) AS ExpireDate