# Formatting a date value in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I am a bit rusty and would be very grateful if you could help. I am using Reporting Services. I am using T-SQL. The date_ordered field mentioned below is data type varchar.

I have a simple report that gives the date_ordered value. Unfortunately, when I ORDER BY date_ordered DESC,  it sorts the date by the numerical value of the day, so 31-Oct-14 appears first and 01-Apr-13 last.

I would like the report to show most recent dates first and end with the last date ordered.

I'm sure it's very obvious, but I can't see it.

With many thanks.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. What does your dataset query look like, where do you do ordering and formatting, etc. Help us reproduce your scenario so we can help out.

Comment: The dataset query is very simple: Select date_ordered, date dispatched, from Orders order by date_ordered. The first value to appear is 31-Oct, the second is 31-May, etc, so it is sorting by the day numerical value, as far as I can see.

Comment: Note that on SO you can *edit* your own question to add more details. This will also bump your question again (comments won't). (PS. The query you posted will *not* be enough for us to reproduce it. Put yourself in our shoes: we need more info to help. E.g. some DDL to create a repro, or at the least table structure, data types, and some sample data.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; hopefully the amended post is slightly less amateurish. It seemed so simple I thought there may be a simple ish solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to convert your date to a datetime format in tsql. then when you sort it it works as expected.

```
Select CONVERT (datetime, '24-04-2012', 105 as date) as date, 
[date dispatched] from Orders order by 1
```

see [How convert string to date T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304373/how-convert-string-to-date-t-sql) and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to reply.