# How do I fix this incorrect syntax in my Code

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run my code, I keep getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'

I've checked & rechecked and I can't get where the error is

```
INSERT INTO stock (ID, GOODSNAME, QUANTITY, PRICE, [DESCRIPTION], GOODSIMAGE, REGDATE) 
    SELECT 
        'STOCK-5', 'Pine by 150 Wipes', 120,600.00, 'To Clean Faeces', 
        BulkColumn 
    FROM 
        Openrowset (Bulk 'ImageDirectory\IMG_20180206_113030.jpg', Single_Blob) AS tb_picture, 
        CONVERT(date, '2011/11/11')
```

Comment: Can you post the Stick table Schema? @Mr. Royal

Comment: also, `CONVERT` had nuances, since your date is confusing enough, please check this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304533/4648586). confusing enough: computer might unable distinguish the month and day apart.

Comment: you have six columns in the insertion list but seven comma sepearted values in th select list.

Answer (score 1):

That expression belongs in the `SELECT` clause not the `FROM` clause:

```
INSERT INTO stock (ID, GOODSNAME, QUANTITY, PRICE, [DESCRIPTION], GOODSIMAGE, REGDATE) 
    SELECT 'STOCK-5', 'Pine by 150 Wipes', 120,600.00,
           'To Clean Faeces', BulkColumn, CONVERT(date,'2011/11/11')
    FROM Openrowset(Bulk 'ImageDirectory\IMG_20180206_113030.jpg', Single_Blob) tb_picture
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your current query slightly better formatted

```
INSERT INTO stock (ID, GOODSNAME, QUANTITY, PRICE, [DESCRIPTION], GOODSIMAGE) 
SELECT 'STOCK-5','Pine by 150 Wipes', 120,600.00,'To Clean Faeces', BulkColumn
FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'ImageDirectory\IMG_20180206_113030.jpg', Single_Blob) as tb_picture
, CONVERT(date,'2011/11/11')
```

The "as tb_picture" in this query is a table alias, not a selection list alias. The FROM clause has passed, you cannot simply add another expression after that. It should probably go between "BulkColumn" and "FROM"

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
INSERT INTO stock (
  ID, GOODSNAME, QUANTITY, PRICE, [DESCRIPTION], 
  GOODSIMAGE, REGDATE
) 
SELECT 
  'STOCK-5', 
  'Pine by 150 Wipes', 
  120, 
  600.00, 
  'To Clean Faeces', 
  BulkColumn, 
  Convert(date, '2011/11/11') 
FROM 
  Openrowset (
    Bulk 'ImageDirectory\IMG_20180206_113030.jpg', 
    Single_Blob
  ) as tb_picture
```